# Documenting django rest framework using sphinx

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, python-sphinx

I just got started with [sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/contents.html), went through it's documentation I was able to document my class models in `models.py` which is pretty much straight forward. The next thing I want to do is documention in `views.py`. 
 Does sphinx have a standard way of documenting **HTTP** methods? if so kindly share snippets on how to implement such.

Comment: Offtopic: you might be interested in drf swagger (package drf-yasg) for automatic end-point documentation

Comment: I know about  drf swagger but I don't want to use it I am documenting everything from  the `models.py` and also `views.py`. I have found sphinx-contrib which does the job I want  https://github.com/sphinx-contrib/httpdomain

Comment: I am trying to achieve the same thing. Is there any other tool than swagger and sphinx-contrib/httpdomain? My problem with sphinx-contrib is that everything has to be documented in the views. Yet, I would like to document my URLs...